# Java MAPI for MS Exchange 2007

Tags: java, exchange-server, mapi, exchange-server-2007

I am looking for solution to connect Exchange 2007 from Java SE 6. The problem is, server has OWA enabled, WebDAV disabled, SMTP/IMAP/POP disabled, EWS disabled - that's the reason I have to use MAPI. I found only one library - **Exchange Connector** from Moonrug Software. Do you know any other solutions using MAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a 1 stop solution but we use [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) together with [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). Redemption is a COM library that wraps MAPI and CDO to make life much easier with MAPI and JACOB is a Java-COM bridge

Comment: I'm going to check Your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ActiveSync to connect to your Exchange Server? If yes, ActiveSync uses simple HTTP POST requests, and the protocol is fully [specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425499(v=EXCHG.80).aspx). It is not free though (it is licensed). Not sure if this helps.

Comment: There is one Java implementation of ActiveSync I am aware of: http://code.google.com/p/synku4j/